# Reorder Buffer: Pointer values when it is full?

Tags: buffer, cpu-architecture, microprocessors, circular-buffer

The re-order buffer used in the Tomasulo's algorithm for out-of-order execution and branch speculation has 2 pointers.

- Head pointer: Points to the oldest instruction. This will be the next
  instruction to be committed.
- Tail pointer: Points where the newest instruction will be added.

Each ROB entry has 4 fields: instruction type, destination, value and ready field.

I've seen many sources teaching it this way. The ROB entry doesn't need a committed bit or busy bit.

For a ROB of size N.

- If the ROB is empty or flushed, then TAIL=HEAD.
- If the ROB has one free slot and HEAD=0, then TAIL=N-1.
- If the ROB is full and HEAD=0, then TAIL=?

If TAIL=HEAD how do we know if the ROB is full or empty?

Answer (score 1):

Normally it's a *circular* buffer (indices wrap around); the almost-full state doesn't have to have HEAD=0, just an arbitrary position.

Yes, there's an ambiguity between full vs. empty if you use HEAD and TAIL read/write indices.  As the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) explains, one way to solve that is by tracking used-capacity which can go from 0..n instead of only 0..n-1.

For thinking about CPUs, this is an implementation detail where it doesn't matter exactly *how* the hardware solves it; it's safe to assume that it correctly and efficiently implements a circular buffer that can use all its entries.  (Or unlikely, the effective ROB size is 1 less than the physical ROB size.)

---

BTW, your model with `HEAD=0` corresponds to adding instructions at the current tail, but retiring (committing) by shifting all entries down to 1 index lower instead of moving `HEAD`.  In a *circular* buffer, the condition to watch for is `HEAD = (TAIL-1)%n` or something like that.